# My code creates a soundboard that can assign a sound to a key on a keyboard while listening to keyboard strokes in parallel

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multiprocessing

My code works but I am looking for an efficient way to implement the idea with out having to repeat the same code block inside the function Recin() (record Input function is stated in the code) in order to assign a new key. I'm using windows for this project.
here is the code:

```
import playsound as ps
import keyboard as kb
import concurrent.futures



def recin(): #record input and return a string based on each key it is a while loop because I want it to listen in parallel and the return key value. Return ,based on my research ,initiates the break function so the function will not continue after returning a value
    k0 = "." #example keys
    k1 = "e"
    x=0
    while True: #in order to assign a key I need to  create a code block that looks like the ones here
        if kb.is_pressed(k0):
            return k0
        if kb.is_pressed(k1):
            return k1 


#here is the part that plays sounds and assigns them to keys:
def sp(file,key):   #play a sound after receiving a string as an input then reinitiates the recin func in hopes of changing the f1.result value to avoid endless loop over the same sound
    global f1  #f1 is a processes that will start in parallel and will return the user input 
    user_input = f1.result() 
    if user_input == key:
        ps.playsound(file,False)
        user_input = ""
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:  # rerun the parallel process after shutting down because once the code returns a value it will break the while loop by default
           f1 = executor.submit(recin)


#here is how the code will look like while using the functions stated above:
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:  #intiates recin in parallel just to get the code working
        f1 = executor.submit(recin)


    while True: #sp() example
        sp("sound file","e")
        sp("another sound file",".")
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. (The performance requirement being *stage performance*?) Does or doesn't the code presented [*work as intended*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? `here is the part that is supposed to…` instils doubt.

Comment: I am hoping to make this code suitable for anyone that has the code or at least for my personal use And yes it does work as intended  but I know it can be made more efficient and maybe even faster. in addition I see this as an opportunity to learn more about code efficiency and optimization.

Comment: @Eternal well, it doesn't handle multiple keys pressed at once - that might be kind of limiting for a soundboard app, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please don't edit the code in the question after it has been answered. For details, see: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/22697

Comment: The code cannot possibly run as `: re #` is a syntax error. As such I have closed the question for being broken. Since the question is now off-topic [edits to make the question on-topic are allowed](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7051), so I have rolled back to revision 3 which fixed the syntax error. I then reopened the question. Please do not roll back to revision 2 (making the question off-topic) or 4 (breaking our no edit rule), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I shall work with the assumption that the "playing sound" part works fine.

Firstly, congratulations! The concept you came up with to resume the execution of the `recin` function is known as a [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), and it is available in Python natively through [generators and the `yield` keyword](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Rewriting your code to use generators and still polling the keyboard:

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb

def recin(keys):
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        key_status = {key: kb.is_pressed(key) for key in keys}
        if any(key_status.values()):
            yield key_status

def soundboard(keymap):
    for key_status in recin(keymap):
        for key, is_pressed in key_status.items():
            if is_pressed:
                # kb.release(key)
                print(f"\n{key}: {keymap[key]}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_keymap = {
        'e': "sound file",
        '.': "another sound file"
    }
    soundboard(example_keymap)
```

Note that for purposes of testing I have replaced you `ps.playsound(file, False)` with a simple `print` statement with some debugging info. Also note the `time.sleep(0.1)` call, I found that while testing on Mac the `keyboard` package maybe somewhat buggy and was not clearing the `is_pressed` status fast enough, so I was getting repeat events. I guess initializing the `ProcessPoolExecutor`s in your code is sufficiently slow that this doesn't become a problem.

Note another design choice here: instead of creating separate key handlers running concurrently, I choose to poll the pressed status of all keys we are interested in and store it in a dictionary.

However, this remains a sort-of wasteful approach, as the CPU has better things to do than sit around polling the keyboard. Thankfully, the `keyboard` package allows us to register event handlers, which are functions that can be made to run when a particular key is pressed. The scheduling of these handlers can now be left up to the module, and is no longer our problem!

See this approach:

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb

def soundboard(keymap):
    for key in keymap:
        kb.on_press_key(key, lambda key_event: print(f"\n{key_event.name}: {keymap[key_event.name]}"))
    while True:
        try:
            sleep(0.05)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_keymap = {
        'e': "sound file",
        '.': "another sound file"
    }
    soundboard(example_keymap)
```

Now, you should agree that this is very simple! But it has a problem - as far as I can find out, this only allows handling a single keypress at a time (the backend is not capable of processing all the key events concurrently). You need the `sleep` call here too, otherwise since there is no background thread spawned for the keyboard event handlers, the program will quit immediately. Now, we have a case to use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` you had reached for earlier:

```
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor
import keyboard as kb

def do_for_key(keymap, key):
    kb.on_press_key(key, lambda key_event: print(f"\n{key_event.name}: {keymap[key_event.name]}"))
    while True:
        sleep(0.005)

def soundboard(keymap):
    with PoolExecutor() as pool:
       for key in keymap:
           pool.submit(do_for_key, keymap, key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_keymap = {
        'e': "sound file",
        '.': "another sound file"
    }
    soundboard(example_keymap)
```

However, now we have come full-circle to your original implementation - the `sleep` call excepted, this is almost fully equivalent to your original implementation. This, however, still doesn't solve the problem that multiple keys pressed together are not all considered (only the key pressed first will work, the other pressed keys won't do anything). With a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, I don't know why multiple pressed keys don't trigger events - I haven't studied the `keyboard` package in any depth. So to fix that, we come back to a combination of Solution 1 and Solution 2:

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb

keymap_count = None

def do_for_key(pressed_key, keymap):
    global keymap_count
    if keymap_count is None:
        keymap_count = dict(zip(keymap, [0]*len(keymap)))
    for key in keymap:
        if kb.is_pressed(key):
            keymap_count[key] += 1
            print(f"\n{key}: {keymap[key]}; {keymap_count[key]}")

def soundboard(keymap):
    for key in keymap:
        kb.on_press_key(key, lambda key_event: do_for_key(key_event.name, keymap))
    while True:
        try:
            sleep(0.05)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_keymap = {
        'e': "sound file",
        '.': "another sound file"
    }
    soundboard(example_keymap)
```

So, whenever we receive an event that any key we are interested in has been pressed, we check if any other keys of our interest are also pressed, and process them all together! `keymap_count` is a debugging variable for letting me know how many times a key has been pressed.

The 2nd and 3rd examples may work for you on Windows, but macOS support by the `keyboard` library is experimental and the problems I have may not be ones you face. However, I do believe that the final solution is the most robust one for multiplatform support, and does not rely on something as heavyweight as `ProcessPoolExecutor`s.

An other minor note:

- You have comments explaining what `recin` does. Maybe put them in a [docstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring)?

I'm not going to make other comments around style and readability, there are other, more qualified contributors here who can help.

Comment: The second and third actually worked better than the last one they can register more than one key at the same time, but in the last one if you  happen to press any of the unassigned keys with an assigned key the file assigned gets played for the amount of keys pressed at the same time. for example pressing e with w, r ,and q at the same time. which means 4 repetitions of the same sound.

Comment: Edit: I guess why it is that way - there's a
key press event for each key held down together. Hmm, not something I had investigated. Let me try to come up with a solution.

Comment: the code that has the problem is just your last solution the one that is a combination of 2 and 3 I believe, but instead of your print statement  i used ps.playsound from the playsound module to make it play sounds. I believe that this should not have any effects on your code since I also tried the code with your print statement and it still had the same problem

Comment: You can try the updated last example now - I think that code which works on multiple platforms is important. Solutions 2 and 3 might work as you want on Windows, but they don't exactly work ideally on Mac.

Comment: thanks. the updated last solution is great

Comment: btw do you know how to add a pause and continue button and a terminate code button because I've been trying to do that but i always keep coming up with the idea of concurrent.futures but that would ruin the whole point of using the last solution as well

Comment: pause and continue button is, basically, a button that stops the code from recording input and can make it continue at will

Comment: terminate is simple here, Ctrl-C to terminate the program. For pausing, you can use `unhook_key` to remove the event handlers for all other keys except the pause/resume key, and use `on_press_key` to restore the handlers when the pause/resume key is pressed again.

Comment: can you give me an example to that because I kinda just started learning python and coding as a whole. btw i run code from pycharm so the ctrl c thing does not work